# Personalizar o .tofixed para utilizar vírgula como separador decimal

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer com que o `.tofixed(2)` trabalhe com virgulas e não com ponto
como separador decimal.

No caso, quando eu calculo o resultado final fica "501.60" e o certo seria "501,60".

```js
document.getElementById('resultado'+tipo+'_'+index).value = (Valor1 * Valor2).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Use replace após o tofixed para trocar o ponto pela virgula ex: tofixed(2).replace(".",",");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso esteja trabalhando com moedas, a recomendação é utilizar **[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)**.

```js
var numero = 250.8 * 2;

console.log(parseFloat(numero.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
  currency: 'BRL',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
}));

// Output: 501,60
```

Ou ainda...

```js
var numero = 250.8 * 2;

console.log(parseFloat(numero.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
  currency: 'BRL',
  style: 'currency',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
}));

// Output: R$501,60
```

Caso contrário, você pode implementar **[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** (como foi citado no comentário da pergunta)

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema, obrigado pela ajuda ^^